# Order wordpress taxonomy parent terms by their children count

Tags: taxonomy, terms, order, sort

I need to order parent terms by their children count:

```
function sort_terms_by_children_count ( $terms ) {
    $sort_terms_by_children_count = array();
    foreach($terms as $term) {
        $count = count (get_terms( $terms, array( 'child_of' => $term->term_id, 'hide_empty' => false, ) ));
        $sort_terms_by_children_count[$count] = $term;
}
    sort($sort_terms_by_children_count);

return $sort_terms_by_children_count;
}
```

and use it like:

```
$terms = get_terms('product_cat');
$terms = $sort_terms_by_children_count($terms);
```

It doesn't work, outputs only one term.

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Answer (score 1):

there should be no need for this function, you could use $args passed to the get_terms. See: https://codex.wordpress.org/es:Function_Reference/get_terms

`get_terms('product_cat', array('orderby' => 'count'));`

Cheers!

Comment: I want to order parent terms by their children count. Not by post count.